# I am using Codeigniter: simple mail() function in cron job, but in mail its showing via crystal url name server in from section?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Code-igniter: I am using simple mail() function in cron job, but in mail its showing via crystal url name server in from section??

In mail its showing like:

```
from:   Domain Name <noreply@domainname.com> via crystal.urlnameserver.com
```

My code snippet:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Domain Name <noreply@domainname.com>' . "\r\n";
....
mail($mailId, $subject, $mentor_message, $headers);
```

Why its showing "via....." text?? please suggest me the changes??

I didn't mention it anywhere, then why its coming like that?

**My cron job is in pure core-php.**

Comment: That's not controlled by PHP, but how your hosters´ MTA (sendmail/etc.) is configured.

Comment: I did not set anything hosting relevant.. though that text is appearing?

Comment: If you did not set anything hosting-relevant, why are you confused by the hosting defaults getting injected?

Comment: yest 5th parameter solved the problem.. please close the question